# WIndows Server 2012 R2 + Windows 7 Ultimate CD Burn Rights

Tags: active-directory, permissions, domain, domain-controller, optical-media

H have recently installed a ADDC in my office to manage users. I have actually setup roaming profiles and everything is great apart from one little issue... On the PCs standard users are unable to burn any CDs (which they need to be able to do) due to having "no burn rights"...

I have seen some XP issues resolved locally on each PC (http://www.rodneybeede.com/CD_Burn_rights_in_XP_for_non-admin_users.html) however I feel that there must be a way to do this through a group policy or some such way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you've linked are exactly how it would be done via a group policy.

Edit the group policy on your domain which applies to the client computers (i.e. that which applies to the OU in which the computer objects are in the directory), and set the value of "Devices: Allowed to format and eject removable media" to "Administrators and Interactive Users".  You'll find the interface very familiar if you followed the instructions you linked, since gpedit.msc is the group policy editor.

I suspect that the restriction of CD-ROM use to the interactive user is unnecessary but you can do it anyway if you want.

Comment: Falcon, i reached the same realisation that i could edit the GPO on the domain. and was just about to answer my own question when I saw you beat me to it.

Thanks for your help though